# building pgBackRest for rhel8 - "library 'yaml' is required"

Tags: postgresql

I am aiming at building the pgBackRest package for rhel8 environment based on the [pgBackRest manual](https://pgbackrest.org/user-guide-rhel.html#build). Which starts with some errors on installing some build dependencies

`yum install make gcc postgresql10-devel openssl-devel libxml2-devel lz4-devel libzstd-devel bzip2-devel libyaml-devel`

After having replaced the unknown to dnf packages `postgresql10-devel` (with `postgresql-server-devel` & `libyaml-devel` (with `libyaml`) as alternatives I still am stuck with the build.

```
# cd /build/pgbackrest-release-2.39/src && ./configure && make
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for pg_config... yes
checking for PQconnectdb in -lpq... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking libpq-fe.h usability... yes
checking libpq-fe.h presence... yes
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for EVP_get_digestbyname in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_new in -lssl... yes
checking for pkg-config... yes
checking for xmlSaveToBuffer in -lxml2... yes
checking libxml/parser.h usability... yes
checking libxml/parser.h presence... yes
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for yaml_parser_initialize in -lyaml... no
configure: error: library 'yaml' is required
```

the closing error sounds a bit like `libyaml`, but as I have this installed I can't make much sense if it.

Can anybody kindly advise on how to get going with this?

Answer (score 1):

The PowerTools repo should contain the libyaml-devel package needed for the build:

```
$ sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```